# Mockito: parameter's mocked service throws null pointer exception

Tags: junit, mockito

Having this controller method to test

```
@RequestMapping("/search/{q}")
public String getWeatherForSearchTerm(@PathVariable String q, Model model) {
    GeocodingResult geocodingResult = geocodingService.findBySearchTerm(q);
    Weather weather = weatherService.findByLocation(geocodingResult.getGeometry().getLocation());
    model.addAttribute("geocodingResult",geocodingResult);
    model.addAttribute("weather",weather);
    return "weather/detail";
}
```

trying to run this test

```
@Test
public void getWeatherForSearchTermTest() throws Exception{
    GeocodingResult geocodingResult = new GeocodingResult();

    Weather weather = new Weather();

    Mockito.when(geocodingService.findBySearchTerm("13")).thenReturn(geocodingResult);

    Mockito.when(weatherService.findByLocation(any(Location.class))).thenReturn(weather);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/search/13"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view()
            .name("weather/detail"));
    Mockito.verify(geocodingService).findBySearchTerm(any(String.class));
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException while trying to do this code line  inside the Controller

```
Weather weather = weatherService.findByLocation(geocodingResult.getGeometry().getLocation());
```

Even if

```
        Mockito.when(weatherService.findByLocation(any(Location.class))).thenReturn(weather);
```

is defined.

After debugging I realized that this is the part which is throwing the exception.

```
    geocodingResult.getGeometry().getLocation()
```

I dont understand why is this happening if I mocked the response as shown above on the snippet code.

My class is annotated with

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

and the memeber class are defined:

```
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private WeatherController controller;

@Mock
private WeatherService weatherService;

@Mock
private GeocodingService geocodingService;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the stack trace.

Comment: It is throwing a nullpointer exception on the line I have highlighted, I have debbuged and saw that what is throwing the nullpointer is geocodingResult.getGeometry().getLocation()

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the mocking. Issue is, you are returning a shallow object of `GeocodingResult`. Underlying attributes of GeocodingResult such as `geometry` are not set explicitly hence they must have been initialized to null.

You need to do something like

```
@Test
public void getWeatherForSearchTermTest() throws Exception {
    Geometry geometry = new Geometry();
    // Assuming location is string
    geometry.setLocation("Mars");

    GeocodingResult geocodingResult = new GeocodingResult();
    geocodingResult.setGeometry(geometry);
    // remaining code here
}
```